# Git: how to check out the currently pushed branch in the pre-push hook?

Tags: git, githooks

In my project I have a pre-push git hook that runs unit tests on every push.

But when I try to push changes from one branch while staying at another one, the unit tests will be run for the active branch, not for the currently pushed one.

For example, if I try to push changes from my new_feature branch while my working directory reflects the structure of the develop branch, the pre-push hook will run the unit tests for the develop branch, not for the new_feature.

The basic idea to get rid of this is to make a checkout of the currently pushed branch in the pre-push hook. But I have no idea how to get information about currently pushed branch inside the hook: this information is not contained in the hook arguments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html) of `githooks`:

```
Information about what is to be pushed is provided on the hook's standard input
with lines of the form:

   <local ref> SP <local sha1> SP <remote ref> SP <remote sha1> LF

For instance, if the command git push origin master:foreign were run the hook would
receive a line like the following:

   refs/heads/master 67890 refs/heads/foreign 12345

although the full, 40-character SHA-1s would be supplied.
```

in which  is exactly the branch you are pushing. With it you can checkout and test in that working tree.

Here is a sample hook-script:

```
#!/bin/sh

z40=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

IFS=' '
while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do
    current_sha1=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
    current_branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
    if [ "$local_sha" != $z40 ] && [ "$local_sha" != "$current_sha1" ]; then
        git checkout $local_sha

        # do unit testing...

        git checkout $current_branch
    fi
done

exit 0
```

Answer (score 3):

The pre-push hook (introduced with [git 1.8.2, April 2013](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt#L167-L168)) has been introduced by [commit ec55559](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ec55559f937727bcb0fa8a3dfe6af68c188e968a), along with [this sample](https://github.com/git/git/blob/87c86dd14abe8db7d00b0df5661ef8cf147a72a3/templates/hooks--pre-push.sample):

> This hook is called by '`git push`' and can be used to prevent a push from taking place.
>   The hook is called with two parameters which provide the name and location of the destination remote, if a named remote is not being used both values will be the same.
>
> Information about what is to be pushed is provided on the hook's standard
>   input with lines of the form:

```
<local ref> SP <local sha1> SP <remote ref> SP <remote sha1> LF
```

> For instance, if the command `+git push origin master:foreign+` were run the hook would receive a line like the following:

```
refs/heads/master 67890 refs/heads/foreign 12345
```

> although the full, 40-character SHA1s would be supplied.
>
> - If the foreign ref does not yet exist the `<remote SHA1>` will be 40 `0`.
> - If a ref is to be deleted, the `<local ref>` will be supplied as `(delete)` and the `<local SHA1>` will be 40 `0`.
> - If the local commit was specified by something other than a name which could be expanded (such as `HEAD~`, or a SHA1) it will be supplied as it was originally given.

So check if the local ref contains the name of the correct branch, ie "currently pushed branch", provided you provide that same name in your `git push` command (ie do not use `git push` alone).